# one US zipcode for two cities what should i default to?

Tags: postal-code

Can a zipcode contain more than one city. For example, it seems that **Foster City, CA** and **San Mateo,CA** both share the same zipcode: 94404.

i have a data dump that labelled "San Mateo" as a primary city, and "Foster City" as an 'acceptable city'.  which is why I was confused...who determines San Mateo is a primary city.:p

i even noticed Google defaults to the 'primary city' of **San Mateo** when searching only for the zipcode 94404

[image]

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking. If you are asking whether a a zipcode can cover more than one city, the answer is yes.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53918/determining-which-us-zipcodes-map-to-more-than-one-state-or-more-than-one-city gives a fuller answer here-- some zipcodes are in multiple states!

Comment: i have a data dump that labelled "San Mateo" as a primary city, and "Foster City" as an 'acceptable city'.  which is why I was confused...who determines San Mateo is a primary city.:p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a zipcode can cover more than one city. As Barry Carter said in a comment, a zipcode can even cross state boundaries.

I'm fairly sure that that "primary" and "acceptable city" are not official designations. I think the only real way to know the meaning of those definitions is to ask the publisher of the data you are using.